# Plot read coverage along a chromosome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset :

```
> head(tab)
    chr  start   stop       cov
1 chr1A 100000 200000 196.12189
2 chr1A 200000 300000 209.58797
3 chr1A 300000 400000 241.63087
4 chr1A 400000 500000  44.75814
5 chr1A 500000 600000   7.50481
6 chr1A 600000 700000   7.2191

> tail(tab)
        chr     start      stop      cov
90959 chr7B 574900000 575000000 7.569640
90960 chr7B 575000000 575100000 7.895070
90961 chr7B 575100000 575200000 7.393070
90962 chr7B 575200000 575300000 7.713670
90963 chr7B 575300000 575400000 7.384180
90964 chr7B 575400000 575474131 7.029839
```

Col1 : chromosome name (from chr1A to chr7B)

Col2&3 : Position on the chromosome (window size 100kb)

Col 4 : coverage associated to the window

I need to plot the "cov" variable for each "chr" , along the "start" and "stop" positions. I use :

```
ggplot(tab) + aes(x=start, y=cov, xend=stop) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~chr)
```

[image]

I would like to improve this graph. Because each plot has the same highest x and y-axis :

- set up the x and y axis for each chromosome : I mean, if the highest "cov" for "chr1A" is 200, set up the max y-axis to 200. And so on, give the highest cov values assoiated to each chromosome.
- do the same for the x axis. The highest "stop" value for each "chr" is the size of the chromosome. Each chromosome has a different size

Any help?

Comment: try adding `, scales = "free"` to your facet wrap.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. And any tip to remove the outliers, I mean, I have 2000 as "cov" value for "chr1B", what creates a huge y-axis. Other values are around 50, what makes flat the curve..

Comment: Other than using a log scale, I would say no - that's a feature of the data.  You could consider making it a side-to-side bar chart and use `facet_grid` to make each plot cover the whole of your page width - that would allow for rectangular plots but still easy comparison between chromosomes?

Answer (score 2):

I think `scales="free"` (or `"free_x"`) will solve the x-axis issue, but working with the outliers is a bit more subjective. Depending on the audience of your plot, you can remove them (assuming it is "known" that outliers have been removed) or you can "shift" them into the desired scale and mark then (`shape=`) as out of place.

For instance,

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- do.call(rbind, list(
  data.frame(chr = "chr1A", start=1:50, cov=replace(runif(50, 5, 10), 20, 250)),
  data.frame(chr = "chr1B", start=1:90, cov=replace(runif(90, 5, 10), 80, 2000)),
  data.frame(chr = "chr2A", start=1:20, cov=runif(20, 5, 10))
))
head(dat)
#     chr start      cov
# 1 chr1A     1 9.574030
# 2 chr1A     2 9.685377
# 3 chr1A     3 6.430698
# 4 chr1A     4 9.152238
# 5 chr1A     5 8.208728
# 6 chr1A     6 7.595480
```

The initial plot is similar to yours:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(start, cov)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ chr)
```

[image: ggplot with outliers]

If we set our limits based on our expectations (either subjective or empirically derived, over to you ... I'll just set them statically), we can mark then clearly:

```r
dat |>
  transform(outlier = cov > ylims[2], cov2 = pmin(cov, ylims[2])) |>
  ggplot(aes(start, cov2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outlier)) +
  facet_wrap(~ chr, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("FALSE" = 16, "TRUE" = 4))
```

[image: ggplot with outliers in view but clearly marked]

It doesn't always work, but sometimes I'll include the actual value next to each outlier.

```r
dat |>
  transform(outlier = cov > ylims[2], cov2 = pmin(cov, ylims[2])) |>
  ggplot(aes(start, cov2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outlier)) +
  facet_wrap(~ chr, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("FALSE" = 16, "TRUE" = 4)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(cov, 0),
        hjust = ifelse(start > max(start)/2, 1.2, -0.2)),
    data = ~ subset(., outlier), size = 3, color = "red")
```

[image: ggplot with outliers as Xs and values in red]

I'm using the `~`-expression for subsetting the data used in `geom_text(.)` so that we only show the outliers themselves. (I'm also otherwise using just base R ... feel free to use `dplyr` if you're already using it or more comfortable with it.)

A final alternative is to count the number of outliers (into a new summary frame), remove them from the plot, and add `geom_text(data=summary_frame, ...)` with a simple annotation such as `(2 outliers removed)` from each facet.